# How to demonstrate memory leak and zombie objects in Xcode Instruments?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, nszombie

I would like to demonstrate memory leak and zombie object in Xcode Instruments on a class. I've found it pretty hard to trigger on purpose, especially with ARC turned on. Do you know how could I create them?

Comment: Are you asking how to use instruments or how to cause a leak?

Comment: How to cause a leak - so I can demonstrate the benefits of Instruments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For A leak:

Create two classes, A and B.  A should have an @property that strongly references an instance of B.  B should have an @property that strongly references an instance of A.

```
A *a = [A new];
B *b = [B new];
a.b = b;
b.a = a;
```

That'll create a leak.

### For a Zombie

Create a @property that is of type `assign` (or a variable of type `__unsafe_unretained`.   Then:

```
A *a = [A new];
A.dangerDanger = [NSObject new];
```

That should create a zombie situation;  a dangling pointer, more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to show a leak is to have a class having strong pointer to itself

```
A* a = [A new];
a.leakingpointer=a;
```